# scorecard chart how use date, datastudio

Tags: looker-studio

I would like use latest date value from my table in Scorecard, 
Any idea how to import this Date value in DataStudio report ?
There is no option like "Max Date", similiar to Max value used in Digit  Values.
There is only Count option:

Or advice how to insert date as Label to another ScoreCard chart.

[image]

2)
One more question: Is it possible to insert date function in Text field? Probably not right ? If I wanna join my line of text with some Date
[image]

Hi Nim thanks for help and what about if I want show last data from last 3 days in 2 item dimension table ? In one item I can just use row filter, but how in 2 item ? 
In my case for example most 5 countries by last 3 days, by now I can only show most 5 countries by last day:
...Actually I can setup in the bottom option : date range (last 7days), but I have still too many rows, solution should be somehow limit number of rows per day...somehow

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Question 1: How to display the Max Date LIKE a Scorecard?

**1.1) Data Tab**
- ***Chart Type***: [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044)
- ***Dimension***: Date
- ***Sort***: Date in descending order
- ***Rows per page***: 1

**1.2) Style Tab**
- ***Show Header***: Deselect
- ***Row Numbers***: Deselect
- ***Show Pagination***: Deselect
- ***Table Labels Font Size***: As required (e.g. 24px)

**1.3) Text Box**
- Add a Text Box stating Max Date if required
- ***Precision Movement***: Use Shift + Movement keys to finely place the components exactly where required.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c0266da3-0453-478c-a9fb-4c0fcc05816d/page/H3VRB) and GIF to expand on the above:

[image]

### Question 1 (Original Post - Currently doesn't work as expected): How to display the Max Date on a Scorecard?

At the Metric field of the [Scorecard](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479), create a *Chart-level* [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) that explicitly aggregates the `Date` field by [`MAX`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583208):

```
MAX(Date)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c0266da3-0453-478c-a9fb-4c0fcc05816d/page/PbhOB) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

### Question 2: How to display the latest Metric?

**2.1) Data Tab**
- ***Chart Type***: [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044)
- ***Dimension***: Date
- ***Metric***: As required (e.g. Sessions)
- ***Sort***: Date in descending order
- ***Rows per page***: 1

**2.2) Style Tab**
- ***Show Header***: Deselect
- ***Row Numbers***: Deselect
- ***Show Pagination***: Deselect
- ***Table Labels Font Size***: As required (e.g. 24px)

**2.3) Overlay**
- Add a shape or text box over the Date field part of the Table to ensure that it's not visible and set the colour of the shape to a solid colour that blends in with the background (such as White for a White coloured background).
- ***Order***: Ensure that the shape or text box is placed in front of the Table.
- ***Precision Movement***: Use Shift + Movement keys to finely place the components exactly where required.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c0266da3-0453-478c-a9fb-4c0fcc05816d/page/5FwOB) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]