# how create table / scorecard with last Date value in DataStudio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have this report, but I am not able to create scorecard or table with with latest date value.
Before it was working in Scorecard with MAX(date) query, but I got info that "Scorecard not working this way anymore after last update", but seems that also in table not working.
When you check the screenshots there is showing only type (Text) and not date type as expected.
Any idea how to fix this please ?

FYI: now is showing in report last update from May 28, even there is also data May 29, but it sorted now according SUM(Confirmed) Values , unable to sort by date

Here is my report and some screenshots

https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/6e242aa8-9cda-47c4-8ef5-e52a7148d9bd

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapted from an [Earlier Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61568620/12892553), using an [Editable Copy of the Google Data Studio Report above](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/18a93177-fb5c-4f16-a3d9-32d068d9f62f) and a GIF to elaborate (feel free to have a look through and copy and paste the Table created below, in your report):

**1) Data Tab**

- ***Chart Type***: [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044)
- ***Dimension***: `date`
- ***Sort***: `date` in Descending order
- ***Rows per page***: 1

**2) Style Tab**

- ***Show Header***: Deselect
- ***Row Numbers***: Deselect
- ***Show Pagination***: Deselect
- ***Table Labels Font Size***: As required (e.g. 24px)
- ***Cell Border Colour***: Transparent

**3) Text Box & Grouping**

- Add a Text Box stating Max Date if required
- ***Precision Movement***: Use Shift + Movement keys to finely place the components exactly where required.
- [Groups](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9209580): The Text Box and Table can be grouped so that it's treated as a single component, making it easier to move both components simultaneously

[image]

Answer (score 9):

- Create a new field;
- Type LAST(Your_field_here);
- Insert it in a score card as a metric;
- Remove date range.

Comment: Is there documentation for what `LAST` is? Does it only work on dates or on other types as well? Should I sort prior to applying `LAST`?

Answer (score 0):

There is an hack if you want to show the last date value. You can create a table with the metric "New Case World Wide", sort the table by date and only show one value. Then you can edit the style settings of the table. You can remove the header and the footer of the table and you will have only the value you need.

I also had a difficulty with this feature. I didn't found anything other than this solution. There is nothing related to this in the documentation (link at the end of the post) so I suppose that it is not supported by Google Data Studio currently.

Documentation about scorecards: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479?hl=en

Documentation about calculated fields:
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I just accidentally threw INSERT> DATE RANGE SETTINGS into the presentation and we set some range and it shows the last values beautifully.
Probably later you can somehow automate it, so that you do not have to set the date every time.

I'm new to Data Studio (I've been doing it for 2 days) and I had a problem to show the last value. And I accidentally came across a way that shows me LAST VALUE and even showing the difference (percentage decrease or increase) works.